# MySQL tables are not aligned right

Tags: mysql

I have a question which relates to MySQL. The problem can be seen in these two images:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLO4l.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLO4l.jpg#1

Does anyone know why MySQL is doing this? It should show up as a nice and neat table, not this  bundle of gibberish. Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: Maybe you could try `SELECT * FROM contact_info\G`

Comment: It's not mysql, but your terminal does that

Comment: is there anyway to fix it?
I want it to look like this table:
http://imgur.com/1zP6uVX

Comment: making the terminal wider doesn't help. how do I select fewer columns?

Answer (score 1):

First, to show that there's nothing really wrong, try this query:

```
SELECT firstname FROM contact_info
```

That should look good. Now try this:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname FROM contact_info
```

That's how you pick individual columns.

Really you want to capture output to a file, this page shows you how: [The MySQL Command-Line Tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html)

Then you can learn to use other programs to format it nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you created your table somewhat like this:

```
create table automobile (make char(10),model char(10),year int, color char(10), style char(50), MSRP int);
insert into automobile values ('Ford','Mustang',2006,'Blue','Convertible',27000);
insert into automobile values ('Toyota','Prius',2005,'Silver','Hybrid',22000);
insert into automobile values ('Toyota','Camry',2006,'Blue','Sedan',26000);
insert into automobile values ('Dodge','1500',2005,'Green','Pickup',26000);
```

so a

```
 describe automobile
```

will show you your columns as:

```
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| make  | char(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| model | char(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| year  | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| color | char(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| style | char(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| MSRP  | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

as long as your columns in total are smaller than your terminal's width you should see 
the expected result:

```
mysql> select * from automobile;
+--------+---------+------+--------+-------------+-------+
| make   | model   | year | color  | style       | MSRP  |
+--------+---------+------+--------+-------------+-------+
| Ford   | Mustang | 2006 | Blue   | Convertible | 27000 |
| Toyota | Prius   | 2005 | Silver | Hybrid      | 22000 |
| Toyota | Camry   | 2006 | Blue   | Sedan       | 26000 |
| Dodge  | 1500    | 2005 | Green  | Pickup      | 28000 |
+--------+---------+------+--------+-------------+-------+
```

if you'd like the result smaller then pick the columns you'd like to see e.g.

```
 select make,model from automobile

mysql> select make,model from automobile;
+--------+---------+
| make   | model   |
+--------+---------+
| Ford   | Mustang |
| Toyota | Prius   |
| Toyota | Camry   |
| Dodge  | 1500    |
+--------+---------+
```

to make the content of a column smaller you may use the left string function

```
select left(make,4) as make, left(model,5) as model,left(style,5) as style from automobile;
+------+-------+-------+
| make | model | style |
+------+-------+-------+
| Ford | Musta | Conve |
| Toyo | Prius | Hybri |
| Toyo | Camry | Sedan |
| Dodg | 1500  | Picku |
+------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try supplying a line separator character in the end.

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE *file_path* INTO *table_name* LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Separator character may vary for editors. In Windows, most editors use `'\r\n'`.